# Convert Bitmap Image to DotImaging IImage format

Tags: c#, .net, screenshot, accord.net

What I am currently doing is:

- Capture Some Screen shots
- Copy All the captured Screen Shots in a Bitmap List: List
- Save All the Screenshots in List to hard drive
- Feed All the pictures in the directory to the `VideoWriter` Object of `DotImaging` Library.

My source code for writing the video is:

```
private void MakeVideo()
{
    var saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog { Filter = @"AVI Video(.avi)|*.avi" };
    if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using (var videoWriter = new VideoWriter(saveDialog.FileName, new Size(_screenWidth, _screenHeight), FrameRate, true))
        {
            var ir = new ImageDirectoryCapture(_path, "*.jpg");
                
            while (ir.Position < ir.Length)
            {
                IImage image = ir.Read();
                videoWriter.Write(image);
            }

            videoWriter.Close();
            DeleteFiles(); // Deletes The Files from hard drive
        }
    }
}
```

**What I want to do is:**

- Skip the saving screenshots in hard drive.
- Feed the List to the Video Writer Object directly.

I am unable to do so because it takes the directory path and not the images itself directly.
I want to do it because of the fact that writing all images to hard drive and then making video is much slower, Any Alternatives of DotImaging are also good.

Or maybe you can let me know if I can cast Bitmap Images to the IImage Format that `VideoWriter.Write()` method is accepting as a parameter.

Comment: This library seems to be built around files, not streams unfortunately. Maybe you can modify whatever leads up to [`ImageIO.LoadUnchanged`](https://github.com/dajuric/dot-imaging/blob/320d2cf1301a1b46b1d51abdcc95a7cda72f5ea0/Source/IO/ImageIO.cs) to use `byte[]` or `Stream` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension library called DotImaging.BitmapInterop.

Once it's installed in your project, you can write something like:

```
IEnumerable<Bitmap> frames = GetFrames();

using (var writer = new VideoWriter(target), new Size(width, height)))
{
    foreach (var bitmap in frames)
    {
        var imageBuffer = bitmap.ToBgr();
        writer.Write(imageBuffer.Lock());
    }
}
```